# jquery ajax request seems to hang after a few requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have several objects on my page that I iterate through and make an ajax request to request the status either on or off.  They are lights controlled by homeseer automation software.

Using firebug I can see all the being made and the responses coming back.  when I press a light, I check the status of all lights, in case the status for the lights has changed.  After about the third click, I can see all the requests being made but no response coming back.

Jquery passes the url to a PHP script which makes the call and returns the data to jquery this gets around cross domain security.

I can open up another tab and copy the url post statement into the address and the page displays the response.

Am I not closing something when I have finished with my request/ why after the third click are requests made but no response back???

here is my code

```
function X10Check(){
                            //This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code
                            $('div.lightchk').each(function(i, obj) {

                            $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
                            var element = $(this);
                            var data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device ;

                            $.ajax({                  
                            url:"urlencode.php",
                            data: data,
                            type: "POST",
                                success: function(data) 
                                { 
                                myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
                                var Nmyd = myd.charAt(3);
                                if (Nmyd ==':')Nmyd = myd.charAt(4);

                                if (Nmyd == '2'){element.removeClass('off').addClass('on')}else{element.removeClass('on').addClass('off')};    
                                },
                                error: function (request, status, error) 
                            {   
                              //  alert(request.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            });
                            };
```

it makes a php call here is the php call using the php script allows me to get around cross domain security issues.

```
  <?php
  //set POST variables
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  unset($_POST['url']);
  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
  }
  rtrim($fields_string,"&");
  //open connection
  $ch = curl_init();
  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  $url .= '&';
  $url .= $fields_string;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  //execute post

  $string = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  ?>
```

Comment: Please, try to post properly indented code.

Comment: when I had similar issue, adding cache:false to the ajax call solved it.

Comment: It could be, that you fire request's to often in your `$.each`, but its hard to tell without an example. And the ohter thing that could be is, that the your request to the X-Domain is beeing blocked, after some request's.